# Remove white and unnecessary space from Chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, whitespace

I have a chart and I've added it to a panel but as you can see in the picture, the chart does not fill the whole panel. it has a lot of white space that I highlighted in red.

How can I remove this space on the left, right and bottom of my chart so that it fills the panel?

I tried docking it and I also changed its margin property to false but these solutions did not work.

My chart is .NET WinForms chart:

[image: My chart is .NET WinForms chart]

Comment: What kind of chart? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, some third party control? Please specify the exact type of the chart control.

Comment: my chart is WinForms chart

Comment: Are you using a third party library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can manually set the `ChartArea`'s `ElementPosition` like this:

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
CA.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

This means: Set it to the Top Left and make it fill the chart to `100%`.

The remaining white space is needed for the labels; you can tweak it further still by using numbers **less than 0%** and/or **greater than 100%**.

Do note that they are **not pixels but percent**, so they will always relate to the whole `ClientSize` of the chart control!

Before and after:

[image][image]

Comment: This can of course also be done in the properties window. You can expand the chart even more by changing the `InnerPlotPosition`, if setting the `Position` to 100% is not enough.

Comment: @TaW: Saved a great deal of time. Thanks!