# How to remove white areas in Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

How can I remove white areas (1,2) and reduce width of axis (3) in chart (C#, Visual Studio 2013). Width of chart about 16000px. 
PS: If width of chart short (1000-2000 px) there are no white areas and width of axis is normally.
[image]

Comment: What code do you use to style the chart? Do you position the ChartArea? Also : See [here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925981/remove-white-and-unnecessary-space-from-chart-control/32926520?s=1|2.1348#32926520)

Comment: I use ca.Position=new ElementPosition(0,10,90,90) and reduce white area in (1). But (2) and whitearea between chartarea and legend are big and very big... You can see http://share.pho.to/AKnNt/fb/original (original width 10500 px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large white spaces are the proportionally enlarged distances.

You can set the positions to smaller values when you enlarge the `Chart` width.

Note that relevant property of the elements you can position is of type `ElementPosition` and that..

- ..its values are not in pixels but in percentages of the respective containers.
- ..the initial values are all set to  `0`, which means `Automatic`.

So you need to calculate the position each time you resize the chart and you can't initially set a single property since the others are still at `0`.

These elements can be positioned:

- The `Chartarea(s)`
- The `InnerPlotPosition` of (each) `Chartarea`
- The `Legend(s)`
- a few others, like `Annotations`, we don't need here

You can also set the sizes of the `Major`- and `MinorTickMarks` from `Auto` to a suitable numeric value. Here is an example that work here for a `Chart.Width` of `16,000` pixels:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Legend L = chart1.Legends[0];

ca.Position = new ElementPosition(0.2f, 5, 99, 90);
ca.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(0.3f, 1, 99.5f, 90);
L.Position = new ElementPosition(99.03f, 5, 0.75f, 22);

ca.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Size = 0.15f;

ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.Position.X = 0.1f;
ca.InnerPlotPosition.X = 0.3f;

Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
ay.MajorTickMark.Size = 0.1f;
```

[image]

Also note that I can't see any way to position the `YAxis` label; so it will usually be off to the left. You can `DrawString` it in the `Paint` event, though:

```
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.TranslateTransform(-20, 180);
    g.RotateTransform(270);
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ay.TitleForeColor))
        g.DrawString(ay.Title, ay.TitleFont, brush, 22, 22);
}
```

I use some suitable values here as well but you will want to work out new ones for other sizes!

---

**But:** I'm not sure whether you should enlarge the chart this way. Instead I believe you should allow  the user to **zoom** in and **scroll** in the **zoomed** chart!

Comment: With Position and InnerPlotPosition I lose graphics. MajorTickMark.Size help me with (3).

Comment: Got it, see my updated answer!