# C# Windows Forms Chart is weird

Tags: c#, charts

I made a C# windows forms and my chart is very strange. My chart has a lot of white borders and the text for Master and Slave is very tiny and pixelated.

Why the Axis is so far away from the borders? How can I fix this?

[image]

```
 // chart1
        // 
        chartArea2.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartArea2.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chartArea2.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartArea2.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chartArea2.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea2);
        legend2.Name = "Legend1";
        this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend2);
        this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(543, 49);
        this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
        series3.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series3.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
        series3.Legend = "Legend1";
        series3.MarkerBorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        series3.MarkerImage = "C:\\Users\\Tiago\\Desktop\\CODIGO_TESE_FINAL_BACKUP1408_BOM\\C# - AR.Drone SDK\\AR.Dron" +
"e\\icone_drone_2_50x50.png";
        series3.MarkerImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        series3.Name = "Master";
        series4.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series4.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
        series4.Legend = "Legend1";
        series4.MarkerImage = "C:\\Users\\Tiago\\Desktop\\CODIGO_TESE_FINAL_BACKUP1408_BOM\\C# - AR.Drone SDK\\AR.Dron" +
"e\\icone_drone_2_50x50.png";
        series4.Name = "Slave";
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series3);
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series4);
        this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1159, 359);
        this.chart1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
        this.chart1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseDown);
        this.chart1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseMove);
        this.chart1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseUp);
```

Comment: We have no clue what is happening if you do not specify some source code and provide what you have tried so far.  Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no code. I just added the chart and used MarkerImages to display the drones

Comment: Which generates code. Please provide us an example of what you have done, with just an image we do not know what is going on. Everything is guesswork.

Comment: Look my edit. I only have code on designer. This will not help.

Comment: Well, this helps a lot, as we now can see quit a few things. Like you have 2 series and the charttype is Point...etc...You also have messed with the Legend, added one with a crazy name.. Do you actually use the Mouse events? Also: Why d you think the charts is so weird? It looks rather ok to me

Comment: Ok. But is there a way to make the axis near the borders? My graph is very little compared to the actual chart control.

Comment: Yes I use the mouse events.

Comment: Do you mean the y-axis? Do you have one or more chartareas? you could [position the chartarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601996/how-to-remove-white-areas-in-chart/39602599#39602599) but it is a bit involved..

Comment: I only have 1 chart area with 2 series. I just wanted to put the y axis near the left border  andx axis near the bottom border. But if it's hard forget it.

Comment: Try this: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position = new ElementPosition(0,0,85,90);`

Comment: it's more near to the left now. I also wanted to make it near the bottom.

Comment: Is there a way to make the Series text bigger? Master and Slave is very tiny.

Comment: I just had to turn 90 into 100. It worked. Can you just tell me if there a way to make the Series text bigger? Master and Slave is very tiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the border spaces and the Fonts all in the designer.

Pick the `ChartArea` and modify the `Position`. Note that it is **not in pixels** but in **percentages** of the `Chart.ClientSize`!! So for your largish chart the 3% defualt is a little too much..

[image]

The `Legend`'s `Font` is changed here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Worked well.