# .NET winform chart control : reduce the white margins on the sides?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

Is there a way to control/reduce the space (see the arrows in the image) wasted on the sides of a chartarea? I tried setting to zero a few properties (i.e. Margin on the chart control, BorderWidth on the chartarea) but without any visible improvement. BTW this wasted space increases as the containing form increases in size.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925981/remove-white-and-unnecessary-space-from-chart-control).

Something like the following satisifies the need

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
CA.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
CA.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(4, 4, 92, 90);
```