# Remove white space between Chart Area and Legends

Tags: c#, .net

How to remove this large blank space between my chart area and the legends? See that I even tried different docking styles but the gap is still there.

Any ideas?

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: You may need to tweak the values -  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925981/remove-white-and-unnecessary-space-from-chart-control/32926520#32926520) but it is hard to tell without seeing any of the code you use.. the 2nd image look a littel as if you actaully have two chart areas..??

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying, here's my code:

Answer (score 0):

I import the data from a CSV file, generated by another application. Every column is a new data series but they are all added into the same chart and chartArea element.

```html
     // Load data from CSV into a DataTable         
            DataTable dataTable = ReadCsvFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName("mqlWeekRace.txt"), false);

            Chart chart1 = new Chart();
            chart1.Height = 1000;
            chart1.Width = 1500;
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");       
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
            // chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
        
            // Line colors
            string[] myColors = new string[] { "Blue", "DarkOrange", "Firebrick", "DarkSeaGreen", "DarkViolet", "Sienna",
                                               "DarkOrchid", "IndianRed", "ForestGreen", "Teal", "MidnightBlue", "DimGray" };
            int colorIndex = 0;
        
            foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                if (!col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Data") && col.ColumnName.Length > 1)
                {
                    chart1.Series.Add(col.ColumnName.ToString());
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
                   
                    chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend(col.ColumnName));      
                    chart1.Legends[col.ColumnName].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Column;
                    chart1.Legends[col.ColumnName].Docking = Docking.Top;           
                    chart1.Legends[col.ColumnName].Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 15);                 
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].XValueMember = "Data";
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].YValueMembers = col.ColumnName.ToString();
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].BorderWidth = 3;
                    chart1.Series[col.ColumnName].Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(myColors[colorIndex]);
                    colorIndex++;
                }

            }
         
            chart1.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = true;
            chart1.DataSource = dataTable;
            chart1.DataBind();
```